# What's the difference between target, srcElement and currentTarget?

Tags: dom-events

I would like to know the difference between srcTarget, target, and currentTarget to use one of those in active class in navbar to add/remove it on mousemove, click

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`srcElement` is a deprecated alias for `target`. Do not use it.

`target` is the element on which the event was triggered.

`currentTarget` is the element that caught the event.

For example:

```
<button id="outer" onclick="foo()">
    <div id="inner">I am a child element</div>
</button>
```

If the user clicks on the `#inner` element, then in the event object sent to `foo`, `target` will be `#inner` and `currentTarget` will be `#outer`.

Here is a comparison of these and other variations on the idea (including deprecated and experimental ones):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets